# AmMap External Navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts, ammap

Is it possible to make AmMap zoom in on a particular location base off latitude/longitude or on a certain marker?

I'm using AmMap to display a list of IPs with their locations.
After the map there is a list of those IPs for easier viewing.

How can I link the IP locations from the list to the map so when I click on them it zooms in on the map ?

Answer (score 0):

If you've got for example:

```
var map = AmCharts.makeChart("mapdiv",{
  "type": "map",
  "dataProvider": {
    ...
  },
  "areasSettings": {
    "autoZoom": true //<-- this is important as well
  }
});
```

And you link the `id` of the [**mapObject**](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptmaps/MapObject) to your IP Location list item.

You can do the following when you've obtained that `id` after clicking on the list item:

```
var mapObject = map.getObjectById(id);
map.selectObject(mapObject);
```

Comment: I considered this method but the IP locations are marked by images. And as far as I know they don't have autozoom property. I suspect there is a way to trick the viewer by zooming on the area while highlighting the image. But how that can be accomplished escapes me.